# Configuring a picklist in CRM Online 2015

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-2015, picklist

We currently have a CRM Dynamics 4.0 system and as part of our Account Entity we have a field **new_accountstatus** with the following set up:

***Schema***

- Display Name: Account Status
- Name: new_accountstatus
- Requirement Level: No Constraint
- Searchable: Yes
- Description: "V1.0"

***Type***

- Type: Picklist
- 1. Overdiew  2. Active  3. Suspended  4.De-Energise  5.Terminated  6.Inactive
- Default Value: Unassigned Value

We are contemplating upgrading and moving to CRM Online 2015 and have created an online trial and as part of the initial configuration we are trying to set up account model and the picklist with similar values and layout.

On creating a new field in CRM 2015 online I can see that the Data Type fields have completely changed. And from the available list Option Set was seemed the most relevant for my needs.

Can anyone explain to me what the Field Type of Simple and Calculated is all about? Also if I try to enter the same values as was in our old system of between 1-6 I get the message:

"The option value you specified does not use this solution's option value prefix (10,000). You should enter a number between 100,000,000 and 100,009,999"

If I enter this as 10,000,001 will this then be read as 1 from the option set as would have been the case in dynamics 4.0 picklist?

Comment: Your questions are not related to software development and therefore off-topic here. Microsoft introduced many breaking changes upon introduction of Dynamics CRM 2011. Refer to the documentation regarding upgrading from 4.0 to 2011.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type you need for your picklist is Option Set.

From CRM 2011 you can choose between local and global (existing) Option Set. If your picklist is used only inside account entity you can create it as local, if it is used in more than one entity (or you plan in the future that this is a possibility) you can create it as global, in order to be reused.

The difference between Simple and Calculated is a feature introduced with CRM 2015, in your case you need Simple (Calculated is in case the value becomes from a calculation, more details here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/lystavlen/archive/2014/11/20/calculated-fields-new-in-crm-2015.aspx)

Regarding the value (1-6). CRM 2011 introduced the concept of Solutions and Publishers, each Publisher can have an Option Set prefix (10000 is the value for the Default Publisher) in order to differentiate Option Set coming from different solutions.

You can still override the prefix, so you can put the values 1-6 if you prefer, the use of the prefix is suggested but not mandatory. the value 100,000,001 is different from 1, so (considering backward compatibility with external system) you should put 1 as value.